# Converting a R2jags object into a Stanreg (rstanarm) object

Tags: r, r2jags, rstanarm

I made a model using `R2jags`. I like the `jags` syntax but I find the output produced by `R2jags` not easy to use. I recently read about the `rstanarm` package. It has many useful functions and is well supported by the `tidybayes` and `bayesplot` packages for easy model diagnostics and visualisation. However, I'm not a fan of the syntax used to write a model in `rstanarm`. Ideally, I would like to get the best of the two worlds, that is writing the model in `R2jags` and convert the output into a `Stanreg` object to use `rstanarm` functions.

Is that possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

I think then question isn't necessarily whether or not it's possible - I suspect it probably is.  The question really is how much time you're prepared to spend doing it.  All you'd have to do is try to replicate in structure the object that gets created by `rstanarm`, to the extent that it's possible with the `R2jags` output.  That would make it so that some post-processing tasks would probably work.

If I might be so bold, I suspect a better use of your time would be to turn the `R2jags` object into something that could be used with the post-processing functions you want to use.  For example, it only takes a small modification to the JAGS output to make all of the `mcmc_*()` plotting functions from `bayesplot` work.  Here's an example.  Below is the example model from the `jags()` function help.

```
# An example model file is given in:
model.file <- system.file(package="R2jags", "model", "schools.txt")

# data
J <- 8.0
y <- c(28.4,7.9,-2.8,6.8,-0.6,0.6,18.0,12.2)
sd <- c(14.9,10.2,16.3,11.0,9.4,11.4,10.4,17.6)


jags.data <- list("y","sd","J")
jags.params <- c("mu","sigma","theta")
jags.inits <- function(){
  list("mu"=rnorm(1),"sigma"=runif(1),"theta"=rnorm(J))
}

jagsfit <- jags(data=jags.data, inits=jags.inits, jags.params,
                n.iter=5000, model.file=model.file, n.chains = 2)
```

Now, what the `mcmc_*()` plotting functions from `bayesplot` expect is a list of matrices of MCMC draws where the column names give the name of the parameter.  By default, `jags()` puts all of them into a single matrix.  In the above case, there are 5000 iterations in total, with 2500 as burnin (leaving 2500 sampled) and the `n.thin` is set to 2 in this case (`jags()` has an algorithm for identifying the thinning parameter), but in any case, the `jagsfit$BUGSoutput$n.keep` element identifies how many iterations are kept.  In this case, it's 1250.  So you could use that to make a list of two matrices from the output.

```
jflist <- list(jagsfit$BUGSoutput$sims.matrix[1:jagsfit$BUGSoutput$n.keep, ], 
               jagsfit$BUGSoutput$sims.matrix[(jagsfit$BUGSoutput$n.keep+1):(2*jagsfit$BUGSoutput$n.keep), ])
```

Now, you'd just have to call some of the plotting functions:

```
mcmc_trace(jflist, regex_pars="theta")
```

[image]

or

```
mcmc_areas(jflist, regex_pars="theta")
```

[image]

So, instead of trying to replicate all of the output that `rstanarm` produces, it might be a better use of your time to try to bend the `jags` output into a format that would be amenable to the post-processing functions you want to use.

---

**EDIT** - added possibility for `pp_check()` from `bayesplot`.

The posterior draws of `y` in this case are in the `theta` parameters.  So, we make an object that has elements `y` and `yrep` and make it of class `foo`

```
x <- list(y = y, yrep = jagsfit$BUGSoutput$sims.list$theta)
class(x) <- "foo"
```

We can then write a `pp_check` method for objects of class `foo`.  This come straight out of the help file for `bayesplot::pp_check()`.

```
pp_check.foo <- function(object, ..., type = c("multiple", "overlaid")) {
  y <- object[["y"]]
  yrep <- object[["yrep"]]
  switch(match.arg(type),
         multiple = ppc_hist(y, yrep[1:min(8, nrow(yrep)),, drop = FALSE]),
         overlaid = ppc_dens_overlay(y, yrep[1:min(8, nrow(yrep)),, drop = FALSE]))
}
```

Then, just call the function:

```
pp_check(x, type="overlaid")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input. "[…] try to bend the `jags` output into a format that would be amenable to the post-processing functions you want to use": my question was probably not clear enough but that's what I'm trying to do. I can actually already use the `mcmc_trace()` and `mcmc_areas()` functions after converting the `jags` output using `as.mcmc()`. There're however other functions that I would like to use that require a `rstanarm` object. E.g. the `pp_check()` function from the `rstanarm` package or the `add_fitted_draws()` from the `tidybayes` package.

Comment: For `add_fitted_draws()` I think it would be pretty difficult.  It relies on all of the underlying infrastructure of an `rstanarm` model.  It seems like it would take a lot of time to try to replicate that.  You might be better off trying to consistently use the same coding conventions in your own code (i.e., `mu[i] <- inprod(X[i, ], b[])` such that it would be easy to generate predictions for new data, which is what `add_fitted_draws()` does.

Comment: As for `pp_check()`, the documentation in `bayesplot` suggests that it's supposed to be generic - allowing other package authors to generate methods for `pp_check` for their own purposes. Answer above edited to show one possible way.

Comment: Thank you for the additional info and for the edit. That's useful even if it only solves half of the problem.